# How can I unbind C-tab from jedi:complete?

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

With `jedi-mode` enabled, the <kbd>C-tab</kbd> is bound to `jedi:complete`.

How can I unbind it so that I can then bind it back to `other-window`?

I've tried:

- `` (global-set-key (kbd "C-`") 'jedi:complete) ``
- `(global-set-key [C-tab] 'other-window)`
- `(global-unset-key (kbd "<C-tab>"))`
- `` (defcustom jedi:key-complete (kbd "C-`")
  "Keybind for command `jedi:complete'."
  :group 'jedi) ``

None of them is getting me the desired results.

Comment: Probably `(define-key jedi-mode-map (kbd "C-tab") nil)` once it's loaded. Minor mode bindings override the global ones

Comment: I don't want to unbind all of them keybindings.

Comment: sorry, forgot the key clause

Comment: `(kbd "<C-tab>")` it should be. It works. Can you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
(define-key jedi-mode-map (kbd "<C-tab>") nil)
```

None of the commands with `global` in them will work, since minor mode key bindings
have priority over global key bindings.

Comment: Why doesn't `(local-unset-key (kbd "<C-tab>"))` work?

Comment: Because it wasn't set locally. There are 3 groups: global, local and mode-related. Local and mode override global. Local overrides mode I think. But once you remove local, mode comes back into play. And so on.

Comment: "local" key bindings almost always refers to the *major* mode's keymap. The local map has precedence over the global map, and all *minor* mode maps have precedence over both the local and global maps. So **minor modes > major mode > global** for keybindings. That's the crucial part, but [there's more to it than that](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/), and you should take a look so you at least have an idea of what you don't know :)

Comment: I see. I knew **local>global**, but I thought it was a separate buffer-local mechanism. Turns
out it just modifies the current major-mode-map.