# IPython on emacs blocks keybindings

Tags: python, shell, emacs, ipython

This is an issue with lots of related questions but none seems to work out for me. I need to use IPython in a similar way as I use <kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell`, but of course with python-related completion. The solution by [abo-abo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17817119/1309352) in this previous question [How to open IPython interpreter in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817019/how-to-open-ipython-interpreter-in-emacs?newreg=cd66cd140be94d7085b1a69254155ece) does the trick. However, it has the secondary effect of disabling keybindings when I am in the IPython buffer (i.e. I cannot, for example, change buffers with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>). Is there any easy way of solving this?

Code from previous answer:

```
(defun ipython ()
  (interactive)
  (term "/usr/bin/ipython"))
```

Comment: related to [How can I unbind C-tab from jedi:complete?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21131372/1309352)

Comment: I just tried with `emacs -q` and `C-x o` works. Any other key bindings don't work?

Comment: I don't know why, but in my case no key binding seem to work (`C-x o`, `C-x C-f`, `C-x k`) even launching emacs with `emacs -q`. The minibuffer also doesn't show any activity (i.e. does not display "C-x" if I press so...). EDIT: If I end the ipython process (i.e. type `exit` to the prompt) the key bindings become functional again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you an idea that it's possible to use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `shell` with ipython:

```
(let ((explicit-shell-file-name "/usr/bin/ipython"))
  (shell))
```

But now tab completion doesn't work. Maybe there is a solution to this, I'm not sure.

I prefer `ansi-term` to `shell` somehow.
By the way, did you know that <kbd>C-c C-j</kbd> calls `term-line-mode` in `ansi-term`?
<kbd>C-c C-k</kbd> switches back to the default `term-char-mode`.
In `term-line-mode` you can move about the buffer with usual navigation bindings etc.

Comment: I don't know if that is what you meant, but I can use `C-c C-j` to recover normal keybindings for the ipython shell from your original answer. However TAB-completion does not work when on `term-line-model` TAB-completion does not work.Personally, I prefer `M-x shell` and would like a ipython buffer that works like it, but this is a good solution for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give python-mode.el a try. `M-x ipython RET` should do it than.

Comment: The ipython terminal that I get with python-mode.el does not handle TAB-completion properly...

Answer (score 0):

the code you posted but insted use ansi-term:

```
(defun ipython ()
  (interactive)
  (ansi-term "/usr/bin/ipython"))
```